# GUI for C++ on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, cocoa

What GUI or framework should I use for both 2D and 3D applications? I'd like to use C++ as much as possible versus other pseudo languages such as Objective C. I'm confused so if this question makes no sense, just please let me know.

Comment: I want to try something more rather than Terminal (command line) app.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. And I think it's off topic here. You should try Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different.

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding this. Are you looking for an IDE, or a framework for creating GUIs for your apps? The first option would be on topic here, but the second is off topic (programming isn't on topic here). If your question is a software recommendation for an IDE, feel free to edit for clarity and flag this so we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [use Xcode for standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282081/how-do-i-set-up-a-c-project-in-xcode-4) programs. You can also [use it with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395721/adding-an-opengl-framework-in-xcode-4).

You can also use [Eclipse for C++](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr1). Here's how to [setup OpenGL in Eclipse CDT for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x).